# how to create Animated drawable in android

Tags: android, animation, vector, drawable

I want to animate the drawable in android as my space screen animation , Here is the vector the I want to animate,

[image]

I want this globe vector to rotate from left to right for 3 seconds, like an earth movement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you want, but you can use this simple library to have svg animation on android

https://github.com/jaredrummler/AnimatedSvgView